# Gulp - passing a paths array to tasks runs but only the last task completes as expected

Tags: gulp

This small snippet below attempts to copy two projects, `projA` and `projB` from their folders into the gulp folder. It passes the paths for the two folders via an array. The code executes correctly but only the last path in the array. So only `projB` is copied over.

```
`const gulp = require('gulp');`

`var pathsToProj = [        // source               // base              destination
                ['../../projA/eb_aws/**/*.*', 'projA/eb_aws', 'gulp-proj1/src/projA/eb_aws'],
                ['../../projB/eb_aws/**/*.*', 'projB/eb_aws', 'gulp-proj1/src/projB/eb_aws'],
              ];    

    pathsToProj.forEach(pathToProj => {`

        gulp.task('copyFiles', function(){
            return gulp.src(pathToProj[0], {base: pathToProj[1]})
                .pipe(gulp.dest(pathToProj[2]));
        });

        gulp.task('default', gulp.series('copyFiles', async function (cb){
            cb();   
        }));
    });
```

Another anomaly is that the project folder is copied to `/gulp-proj1/` (`/gulp/proj1/projB`) and not to `/gulp-proj1/src/` as I intended it to be.

Any help to resolve this is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is because of the combination of `forEach` and gulp's asynchronous nature.  The `forEach`'s will quickly cycle through - without waiting for each function within to complete.  So before the first `copyFile` completes it is called again, which restarts the task and only the last one typically completes.  It is entirely dependent on how fast or slow your internal task takes which is not good.  That internal function should be synchronous to ensure it does what you expect.

For further discussion, see, e.g., [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop) and similar.   Also see
[MDN forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

> **forEach expects a synchronous function**
>
> forEach does not wait for promises. Kindly make sure you are aware of
>   the implications while using promises(or async functions) as forEach
>   callback.

So basically any other `for` type loop would work.  Here is a much simpler version of your code that works:

```
// gulp.task('copyFiles', function (cb) {
function copyFiles(cb) {

  for (const pathToProj of pathsToProj) {

    gulp.src(pathToProj[0])
      .pipe(gulp.dest(pathToProj[1]));
  };
  cb();
};

gulp.task('default', gulp.series(copyFiles));
```

Note for testing purposes I focused on this one issue and not your second question about the destination folder.

Comment: Thanks for that very clear and easy to understand explanation on why my code was not working. I saw other very nerdy explanations on the same i couldn't understand. However this code gives me the same result as mine. It too ran just once copying only one of the 2 project folder to my gulp folder.

Comment: Well, I tested it several times and it worked correctly....and I had three src's in the `pathsToProj`  array so ...

Comment: I have no clue that why it should work on your machine and not mine. I tried to use your code as is.  Really surprising.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code snippet by Mark above as follows to get the desired output:

```
tasks = function copyFiles(cb) {
  var paths = new Array();  
  for (const pathToProj of pathsToProj) {
    paths.push(gulp.src(pathToProj[0], {base: pathToProj[1]})
        .pipe(gulp.dest(pathToProj[2])));
  };
  cb();
  return paths  
};

gulp.task('default', gulp.series(tasks) );
```

However, I still cannot get the folders copied where I want. They end up at /gulp-proj1/ instead of ending up at /gulp-proj1/src/. Thanks.